# Img scr not updating

Tags: javascript, php, image, updating, autofill

so basically what i'm trying to do is to updating the images scr without refreshing the website. Well, it works if i refresh the website but the user can't see that image he choose. So user need to refresh the page first.

**The img tag**

`<img class="tInput" id="ImageType" src="<?php echo $this->item->houses_ImageType; ?>"    alt="0"  />`

**It's a autofill form, the texts works.**

`<input class="tInput" type="text" name="house_video"  id="video" size="50" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $this->houses->video; ?>" />`

`<input name="house_title" value="<?php echo $this->houses->house_title; ?>" class="tInput" id="game_title" tabindex="1"/>`

**The javascript code**

```
                $itemrow.find('#house_title').val(ui.item.itemTitle);
                $itemrow.find('#House_Type').val(ui.item.HouseType);
                $itemrow.find('#ImageType').val(ui.item.ImageType);
                $itemrow.find('#house_video').val(ui.item.itemVideo);
```

In my joomla site i created a small component (with some help), there i create a field with the houses title, image, video,etc... It's connecting to my database, the database field for the image is just a textbox. There i put the image path *(/images/items/house145.jpg)* and that's it.

If users want to search something like house with 3 bedrooms, then all the information is filled automatically, also the image field, but you need to refresh the page then the image is showing up. If users search for 5 bedrooms then he need again to refresh the page, because the image from 3 bedrooms is still showing up.

Did i something missed?

Comment: Images don't have a `val()`, they have an `attr('src')` you need to change.

Comment: While not an issue with your code, there are two places in your question that you mentioned "scr" instead of "src" so be sure you type it correctly when implementing your code.

Comment: I forgot to say it, but I've already tried this: Error in the console; TypeError: "src".item is undefined

Comment: @PcWolf Well, that's not the right syntax. It'd be something like `$itemrow.find('#ImageType').attr('src', ui.item.ImageType);` Assuming `ui.item.ImageType` is a valid URL, of course.

Comment: Thanks for this information, mate! You deserve a cold beer tonight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change image's source with `val` function. You can do it by changing `src` attribute's value.

```
 $(elem).attr('src', newSource);
```

So in your case :

```
 $itemrow.find('#House_Type').attr('src', ui.item.HouseType);

 $itemrow.find('#ImageType').attr('src', ui.item.ImageType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i did something... if i put the **attr**... for all then only the images will work, the textboxes not. Now this is working!

```
        $itemrow.find('#house_title').val(ui.item.itemTitle);
        $itemrow.find('#House_Type').val(ui.item.HouseType);
        $itemrow.find('#ImageType').attr('src', ui.item.ImageType);
```

Answer (score -1):

As per ceejayoz's comment, use .attr('src') for images instead of .val().

```
$itemrow.find('#house_title').attr('src', ui.item.itemTitle);
$itemrow.find('#House_Type').attr('src', ui.item.HouseType);
$itemrow.find('#ImageType').attr('src', ui.item.ImageType);
$itemrow.find('#house_video').attr('src', ui.item.itemVideo);
```